# c# Multi-threaded write to internal dictionary

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have this definition:

```
Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, int>>();
```

I am creating 1000 dictionaries like this in advance:

```
for (int ix=0; ix < 1000; ix++)
    dict[ix] = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

I have 1000 threads where each threads has its own unique index between 0 to 999 and each write data like this:

```
dict[Thread unique Index][Some value] = some value.
```

Will this work or will there be errors in the multi threaded writing ?

I don't want to use ConcurrentDictionary because i have lots of writing and i want to improve performance

Comment: when and how are you adding the key/value pairs?

Comment: If you don't change key collection, then reading dictionary items by key or enumerating is thread-safe. If nested dictionary (value) is never accessed by more than one thread your design is fine. Though it looks like you are more up to `List<Dictionary<whatever>>` (or array) where index is the thread index.

Comment: IMO any design that requires 1000 threads is fundamentally broken...

Comment: @Matthew is right.  If this example is representative of your actual strategy, you are optimizing the wrong thing.  Unless you have 1,000 CPU cores at your disposal, I'd say your time would be better spent figuring out how to better partition the workload than agonizing over the speed of `ConcurrentDictionary` over `Dictionary`.

Comment: "i want to improve performance" - Then better minimize Task-Switches. 1000 Threads will **de**crease performance.

Comment: @Matthew Also, this reminds me of a question on here that asked whether CAS or a `synchronized` update would "cause fewer issues" when **forty thousand threads** are fighting to perform a trivial update to the same variable.  I mean, _really_?

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: Use one dictionary per thread with the aid of the ThreadStatic attribute and merge the content afterwards to your main dictionary (ConcurrentDictionary).

With this approach you have a free hand of your amount of threads.

Answer (score 0):

I assume each thread writes multiple values to this dictionary.

When you use the following:

```
dict[Thread unique Index][Some value] = some value;
dict[Thread unique Index][Some value] = some value;
...
```

It will first look up the "thread specific" dictionary before setting the value. It's much faster to use:

```
Dictionary<int, int> myDict = dict[Thread unique Index];
myDict[Some value] = some value;
myDict[Some value] = some value;
...
```

After this change, the `ConcurrentDictionary` probably won't be the bottleneck.